# PL/SQL input validation technique / utils

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql

Could you please suggest me common PL/SQL input validation technique / utility: digits only, string size restriction, email address, SSN, etc. I've made some google search, but didn't find any library package or source code.  I don't want to re-invent the wheel :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  What version of Forms?  Are you trying to validate the data in Forms?  Or in stored procedures in the database?

Comment: Oracle-11, need to validate input "foo & bar" like: "http://mysite.com?foo=123&bar=xyz" in stored procedures. Thanks.

Comment: to Codo: thank you for suggestion Codo. If I don't find any utility I'll use this technique.

Answer (score 3):

depending on what version of oracle and/or forms i would defenetly use regexp_like if i'd need to validate a string like "mysite.com?foo=123&bar=xyz"

Answer (score 0):

There's a script named dbsmany.sql that perhaps you can find useful in {ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/dbmsany.sql

Is not exactly what you're looking for, but has an interesting approach, the [anydata](http://psoug.org/reference/anydata.html) type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getData(p_x IN sys.anyData)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
 l_num      NUMBER;
 l_date     DATE;
 l_varchar2 VARCHAR2(4000); 
BEGIN
  CASE p_x.gettypeName
  WHEN 'SYS.NUMBER' THEN
    IF (p_x.getNumber(l_num) = dbms_types.success) THEN
      l_varchar2 := l_num;
    END IF;
  WHEN 'SYS.DATE' THEN
    IF (p_x.getDate(l_date) = dbms_types.success) THEN
      l_varchar2 := l_date;
    END IF;
  WHEN 'SYS.VARCHAR2' THEN
    IF (p_x.getVarchar2(l_varchar2) = dbms_types.success) THEN
      NULL;
    END IF;
  ELSE
    l_varchar2 := '** unknown **';
  END CASE;

  RETURN l_varchar2;
END getData;
/
```

For more public and useful PL/SQL scripts:
http://psoug.org/browse.htm

Comment: well... it's a bit different from what I was looking for. But thanks anyway.